# Munkres topology section 25 question 2 B)

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ denote the set of all the (infinite) sequences of real numbers.

Problem 2 (b), Sec. 25 in Munkres: Let $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ have the uniform topology. Then how to show that $x $ and $y$ are in the same component of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ if and only if the sequence 
$$x-y = (x_1 - y_1, x_2 - y_2, x_3 - y_3, \ldots)$$
is bounded?

As I found the answer here..[Probs. 2 (b) and 2 (c), Sec. 25 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Components in the uniform and box topologies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273929/probs-2-b-and-2-c-sec-25-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-components-in-the).    but I'm not getting this in my head.....

[image]

PLiz help me,,,

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4280/henno-brandsma sir  help  me pliz,...

Comment: Please comment on the original answer, if you have questions.

Comment: The first formula is straightfworward computation, as $f$ is a given function. Is the notation unclear?

Comment: The second is a definition of $U$. Nothing to understand, just check that it is an open set.

Comment: for the second deifinition im confused  that    if it  is  bounded ..then why its is open?

Comment: if $z\in U$ then $B(z, 1) \subseteq U$, so $z$ is an interior point of $U$.

Comment: thanks   but  henno  sir..im not getting  first  formula  straight forward computation... Can  u  elaborate   first one  also?

Comment: $$f(s) - f(t) = (x + s(x-y)) - (x + t(x-y)) \\= s(x-y) - t(x-y) = (s-t)(x-y)$$

Comment: thanks@PaulSinclair